# Grails how to call MyUserDetailsService on controller?

Tags: grails, service, spring-security

i have custom MyUserDetailsService

```
class MyUserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {
 ...
}
```

and i want to call in my controller

```
class MyController {
    def springSecurityService

    def check() {
        String user = springSecurityService.principal.username
        def MyUserdetails = MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user)
    }
}
```

and get error

> No signature of method: static
>   MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername() is applicable for argument
>   types: (java.lang.String) values: [user] Possible solutions:
>   loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String),
>   loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String, boolean)

i want to check user after login, so i don't put it in beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your service in the services folder and reference it from your controller:

```
 import your.package.MyUserDetailsService

 class MyController {

        MyUserDetailsService muds
        def springSecurityService

        def check() {
            String user = springSecurityService.principal.username
            def MyUserdetails = muds.loadUserByUsername(user)
        }
  }
```

Comment: oh is my bad to put in src/groovy, now i put in services folder it's work now, btw how to get error message "throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                      'User not found')" from controller? thanks

Comment: sory i get it now, use try catch to get throw exception from service, thanks

Comment: With Grails, the recommended approach is to let the framework handle service injections rather than manually instantiating them. So don't declare a new instance like MyUserDetailsService muds and instead overwrite the default implementation in the resources.groovy file and then just use def userDetailsService to get access to that service's methods.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you would have registered your custom user details service with Grails in the file grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy, like:

```
beans = {
    userDetailsService(com.mycompany.myapp.MyUserDetailsService)
}
```

After you've registered it you can depend on Grails automatic service injection by just declaring a userDetailsService variable in your controller and use it, like:

```
class SomeController {
    def userDetailsService
    ...
    def someAction() {
        String user = springSecurityService.principal.username
        CustomUserDetails userdetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user)
    }
}
```

The documentation [here](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html) is pretty helpful.